# Apache Camel File component base path

Tags: apache-camel

How do I manage to configure the File component of my Camel Context, so that all directory paths provided to its endpoints are prepended with some base path?

For example, if someone writes

```
file:input/customer12?include=.*\.csv
```

it will effectively be

```
file:/usr/local/share/app/exchange/input/customer12?include=.*\.csv
```

For example, I get the component during the Camel Context initialization like this:

```
FileComponent file = CAMELCONTEXT.getComponent("file", FileComponent.class);
```

What do I do next? `createComponentConfiguration()`?

**addition:** It's a standalone cli app which I want to be runnable from any directory

Comment: Start your app under folder /usr/local/share/app/exchange

Comment: Thanks! And what if I want to let a user start the app from anywhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest solution is start your app under folder /usr/local/share/app/exchange , but this is not an option as state in addition requirement

If you have a layer between your user input and your code, then you could inject the path. For example, Java DSL with RouteBuilder.

The last solution is override Camel's file component in component class before it create the actual endpoint.